# What is the most appropriate place for placing (startup) initialization code in a Restlet application?

Tags: initialization, startup, restlet, restlet-2.0

Where can I embed startup initialization code in a Restlet web application, without using a ServletContextListener?

I wish to have transparent deployment of my Restlet to a web server like JBoss/Tomcat and would like to get rid of the initialization logic in the Listener - so as to be able to conveniently deploy it outside of a web server, if the need be - definitely not for heavy production use, but it's valuable nevertheless.

Would inserting it into `org.restlet.Component`'s constructor ensure that it'll only execute once? Is that the right place to put it?

```
public class MyComponent extends org.restlet.Component
{
  public MyComponent() //constructor
  {
    //insert initialization code here that should run ONLY ONCE?

    this.getDefaultHost().attach(new MyApplication()); // MyApplication extends org.restlet.Application
  }
}
```

I went through the docs and also looked at a similar post: [RESTlet startup initialization deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010855/restlet-startup-initialization-deprecated) but I'm still not sure if it's the right way. I would like to remove the dependency on the Listener if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the constructor of the Component is a good place for initialization processing and you can be sure that such processing are only executed once.

You can notice that the method start / stop of the component can also be used in your case. Don't forget to call the super method in them. These methods are called when you start / stop your component that is commonly done once...

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: I guess you don't need to explicitly call `start/stop` when deploying in a servlet container...so I guess the constructor would be the best place. Thanks for the confirmation! Appreciate it.